# JavaFX - Resize and/or move nodes(e.g. TextFields)

Tags: java, animation, javafx, resize, transition

I´m looking for ways to move `nodes`(in my case a `TextField`) as well as resize them.

Below is a basic example:

```
public class Main extends Application{

private static final Pane pane = new Pane();

public void start(Stage stage) {
    TextField txtField = new TextField();
    txtField.relocate(300, 0);
    Button btnS = new Button("Change size");
    btnS.setPrefSize(100, 20);
    btnS.relocate(0, 0);
    btnS.setOnAction(e -> {
        ScaleTransition transition = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(300), txtField);
        transition.setByX(2);
        transition.play();
    });

    Button btnP = new Button("Change Position");
    btnP.setPrefSize(100, 20);
    btnP.relocate(110, 0);
    btnP.setOnAction(e -> {
        PathTransition transition = new PathTransition();
        transition.setNode(txtField);
        transition.setPath(new Path(new MoveTo(300, 50)));
        transition.play();
    });

    pane.getChildren().addAll(btnS, btnP, txtField);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    pane.setPrefSize(500, 100);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
launch();
}
}
```

I want `TextField` to change it´s width only to the right side(so it looks like it´s "sliding"(gets wider) from the left to the right). I think my attempt is wrong, since I don´t want to scale it, but **resize** it(the scaling of the `TextField` works though).
Or is the only way changing the size by creating a loop, which adds amount i to the width for every iteration?

The other `Button` should move the `TextField`. This time I think my attempt is right, however the code doesn´t work, which I can´t explain.

Would somebody help me out here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as changing the width of the `TextField` is concerned. A loop won't work since you'd be blocking the thread responsible for the layout with it. How you can resize the node depends on the parent, since the display width is determined by the parent during layout. In this case you could simply animate the `prefWidth` property using a `Timeline`:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(txtField.prefWidthProperty(), txtField.getWidth())),
        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300), new KeyValue(txtField.prefWidthProperty(), 300)));

timeline.play();
```

---

> The other Button should move the `TextField`. This time I think my attempt is right, however the code doesn't work, which I can't explain.

Take a look at what the path you use looks like. Nothing is drawn, since you only use a single `MoveTo` element. You either need to fix the path or us the much simpler `TranslateTransition`:

```
TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(400), txtField);
transition.setToY(50);
transition.play();
```

**Note:** You may need to adjust the code in order to get the desired effect for repeated clicks.